# My text look behind background position absolute

Tags: css

I have some code that want to make navigation upper than slider bg.
so I insert `position:absolute` to .slider

```
<div class="nav">
        nav
</div>
<div class="slider"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"></div>
<div class="content">content</div>



.nav{
    z-index:99999;
    color:#F00;
    background:transparant;
}
.slider{
    z-index:1;
    top:0 !important;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

The problem is, my content become after my nav so, my content is below my slider and not see it.
How to anticipate this problem which use position absolute so my web still look

```
[[nav]slider

]
[content]
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/luisan/dX49K/

Comment: Create a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/). And we will be able to fix it in seconds and explain.

Comment: i have update and use fiddle, please dont -1 my question

Comment: Im not sure where you want the text, check NoobEditors answer. But you have put `z-index` on if you set it to `-1` the text will appear on top. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/dX49K/1/)

Comment: @Ruddy: yes for nav but i want content after slider... [please dont "-1" my question :( ]

Comment: I didn't `-1` your question. To me its not that bad of a question.

Comment: @Ruddy : `+1`ed...we share same mind these days!! :)

Comment: so, you have any idea?

Comment: @NoobEditor: thanx Noob, you safe my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make other `div` positioned relative, like :

<kbd>[**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/r2Eft/)</kbd>

**HTML**

```
<div id="cont">
    <div class="nav">all nav</div>
    <div class="slider">my slider</div>
    <div class="content">my content</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,body,#cont {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.nav {
    border:1px solid red;
    width:100%;
    height:10%;
    position:relative;/* added */
}
.slider {
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid green;
    left:0;/* added */
    right:0;/* added */
    height:20%;/* added */
}
.content {
    border:1px solid black;
    position:relative;/* added */
    top:20%;/* added - same as absolute div height */
}
```

Comment: @lui : so you want `slider` next to `nav` or below `nav`??

Comment: nav has position 99, slider has below nav as background. after slider is content... so [[nav] slider ][content]

Comment: @lui : mate..u there??

Comment: yes, but for content I want as sample but for #about text. please

Comment: @lui :didn't get u...can you rephrase and ask?

Comment: sorry. I want to make like  the1.sprintheme.com. `.nav` as the nav sample and `.slider` as background slider,,,, `.content` like `#about` as sample. So `#about` us after background

Comment: @lui : mate, what you are asking is known as `parallax` website, with `smooth-scrolling`... its a website feature, do some digging online and comment back if you find the difficulty!!:)

Comment: no, its not parallax website but just simple css. I have found my problem here: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/

Comment: the simple solution as a short way is use .nav as absolute

Comment: @lui :  your `nav` is already `absolute`...check the fiddle i posted in above comments....you `nav` is going to be fixed anyway , so, you need jquery to scroll to clicked `div` in `nav`, that's it fella!!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

z-index will display front or behind of your content

```
<div class="nav"><!--all nav--></div>
<div class="slider"><!--my slider--></div>
<div class="content"><!--my content--></div>
```

**CSS**

```
nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9999; 
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
}
.slider{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    height: 300px;
}
.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

when your z-index is higher then upper div like if your one div z-index is 9 and another is 99 then 99 div is front of all;

best example about z-index.
http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/